# Mysql Record followup

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello all I have a table

"comment" as follows

```
commentid      cmt                followupid    category 

1            hello                   3           starting 
2            hi how are you          4           starting
3            Hello Jhon              5           followup
4            Hi I am fine and you    6           followup
```

I want to echo the records such that When I echo `Hello`  the next comment that will appear is `Hello John`, when I echo `Hi how are you` the next comment that will appear is `Hi  I am fine and you`.
I have  tried to

```
$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM comment where category = 'followup'  AND followupid = commentid ";
```

but it is not working.

Comment: add a column to your db called f_order and give them int 1-x and order your query by f_order asc.

Comment: it does not echo anything. However if i type in the line "SELECT * FROM comment where category = 'followup'" it echoes all the comments.

Comment: 1 - x ? what is x supposed to be? I

Comment: It does not find any row because of "AND followupid = commentid". These two columns are never equal on on row. You should pass the real ID row you want to be followed.

Comment: And the second problem I see is in wrong dtb structure. I think that you should reverse the connections between startings and followups. If you have more than 1 followup for the starting comment, your structure would not handle it. Each followup should carry the ID of it's "parent" (starting item or parent followup).

Comment: I under my first error Lubor Bleik, Thank you for pointing it out. But I can't figure out what you mean by the second problem. I am quite new to all these. :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query as specified will get the results where the followupid is equal to commentid, and you don't have any of those in your example.

For it to work you need to explicitly specify the commentid you're looking for:

`SELECT * FROM comment where category = 'followup'  AND followupid = 3`

in case of PHP, you get this from the current record you're printing:

`echo $row['cmt'];`

`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment where category='followup' and followupid={$row['followupid']}");`

Answer (score 0):

try with SELF JOIN

```
SELECT cb2.comment AS message, cb1.comment AS response
FROM  `chat_box` cb1
INNER JOIN chat_box cb2 ON cb2.followup_id = cb1.comment_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

will return

```
Message |   Response  
Hello   |Hello John  
Hi, how are you Hi, | i am fine and you
```

Comment: yES Indeed i need those to appear as such, but what is cb1 cb2 :S